# Calculating UMVU estimator of an i.i.d sample with Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

First we're given $V_1 = 10$ i.i.d. r.v. $R_i^{(1)} \text{, } i=1, \ldots, 10$, with the distribution

$$ P(R_1^{(1)} = 1)=0,1$$
$$ P(R_1^{(1)} = 0)=0,9$$

Then we have $V_2 = 30$ i.i.d r.v. $R_i^{(2)}\text{, } i=1, \ldots, 30$ with the same distribution.

We know the values

$$Z_j = \frac{S_j}{V_j}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{V_j}R_i^{(j)}}{V_j} \text{, for} j=1,2$$

How can one determine the unbiased estimator $\hat{\mu}$ for $\mu = E[R_i^{(j)}]$ with the smallest variance (i.e. the UMVU-estimator)?

Comment: That was a typo sorry, ubiased is correct!!

Comment: The best estimator for known $\mu=0{,}1$ is $\hat\mu=0{,}1$. This estimator is unbiased and has absolutely minimal variance $Var[\hat\mu]=0$. No samples are needed. Or you should check and correct your question.

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140098/using-corollary-of-cramer-rao-inequality-to-show-hatp-textmle-barx) is strongly related.

Comment: @Harry49 Oh really? In statistics, there is usually an unknown parameter and/or an unknown distribution. And when everything is known, there is no place for statistics. If you can prove that my estimator is not UMVUE, do it.

Answer (score 0):

The sample $(R_i^{(j)})_{1\leq i\leq V_j}$ of i.i.d random variables with distribution $R_i^{(j)}\sim \text{Bernoulli}(\mu)$ has the expected value $\mu = E(R_i^{(j)})$. The Bernoulli distribution belongs to the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family), and the unknown parameter that we want to estimate is $\mu\in \mathbb{R}$. Here, the minimal [sufficient statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) is
$$ S_j = \sum_{i=1}^{V_j} R_i^{(j)} \, . $$
The mean
$$ Z_j = \frac{S_j}{V_j} = \frac{1}{V_j} \sum_{i=1}^{V_j} R_i^{(j)} $$
is a function of $S_j$, and it is an unbiased estimator of $\mu$:
$$ E(Z_j) = \frac{1}{V_j} \sum_{i=1}^{V_j} E(R_i^{(j)}) = \mu \, . $$
Therefore, the mean $\tilde{\mu} = Z_j$ is the UMVU estimator of $\mu$ for the $j$th sample.

The union of two independent i.i.d samples of sizes $V_1$ and $V_2$ is an i.i.d. sample of size $V_1+V_2$. The mean is therefore
$$
\hat{\mu} = \frac{S_1 + S_2}{V_1 + V_2} = \frac{V_1}{V_1 + V_2} Z_1 + \frac{V_2}{V_1 + V_2} Z_2 \, ,
$$
which is a weighted mean of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$.

---

*Notes*

(a) If $\mu = 0.1$ is known when carrying on estimation, then the UMVU estimator of the expected value is simply $\hat{\mu} = \mu$.

(b) In the general case (outside of the exponential family), a complete and sufficient unbiased statistic is needed to be UMVU, which may be more difficult to obtain than a minimal sufficient one.

Comment: I don't think minimally sufficient is enough to get UMVU. You need complete & sufficient (compare to the proof of Lehmann Scheffe theorem). Of course in this case your statement is true since the setup is nice with full rank exponential family.