# Let $X_1...X_n\sim\rm{ Bernoulli}(\theta)$. Show that the variance of the MLE attains the Cramer-Rao lower bound.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I know that the MLE for $\theta$ is the sample mean:

$$\hat \theta = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$$

and that
\begin{align}
Var\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right) &= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \theta(1-\theta) \\
&= \frac{n}{n^2}\theta(1-\theta) \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\theta(1-\theta) \\
&= \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n} \\
\end{align}

I also know that this equality should hold:

\begin{align}
Var\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right) &= \frac{\left(\frac{d}{d\theta}E\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)\right]\right)^2}{E\left[\left(\frac{d}{d\theta} \ln\left(f(X\mid\theta)\right)\right)^2\right]} \\
&= \frac{1}{E\left[\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\theta} -\frac{n - \sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{1-\theta}\right)^2\right]} \\
\end{align}

Can someone show me that $E\left[\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\theta} -\frac{n - \sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{1-\theta}\right)^2\right] = \frac{n}{\theta(1-\theta)}$?

I just don't see it. Someone help me here.

Comment: The sum of the $X_i$ will be a binomial distribution. Calculating the expectation and square expectation then will be quite doable by knowing the mean and variance of the binomial distribution. (I.e. expand out the square and use linearity of expectation)

Comment: There are other expressions for the information function. But finding it is quite unnecessary for the purpose of this exercise.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140098/using-corollary-of-cramer-rao-inequality-to-show-hatp-textmle-barx?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$n \bar x = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$$ Then $$\frac{n \bar x}{\theta} - \frac{n - n \bar x}{1 - \theta} = \frac{n}{\theta(1-\theta)} (\bar x - \theta).$$  Consequently, $$\operatorname{E}\left[\left(\frac{n \bar x}{\theta} - \frac{n - n \bar x}{1 - \theta}\right)^2\right] = \frac{n^2}{(\theta(1-\theta))^2} \operatorname{E}[(\bar x - \theta)^2]. $$  Since you already know $$\operatorname{E}[\bar x] = \theta,$$ then $$\operatorname{E}[(\bar x - \theta)^2] = \operatorname{Var}[\bar x] = \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n}$$ and the rest is straightforward.